# Pi Ethernet to USB router

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

My company has given me a project where I need to provide internet access to a PC via a USB cable connected to the RPi (Model B), which in turn is connected to the router via Ethernet. *I have in my possession the host-to-host USB cable.* What would be the best way to share the connection via USB cable? Is it possible to map one of the Pi's USB ports as a network connector and then repeat the same step with one of the PC's USB ports? Or would it be better to configure the Pi as an RNDIS device, if that is even possible? I am a beginner when it comes to computer networks, so I am a bit lost implementing Ethernet over USB.

**UPDATE:**  I have managed to get the Ethernet to USB bridge working on the Pi. I have connected the USB host-to-host cable to a notebook with Ubuntu and the internet worked just fine. However, I am having trouble with Windows, since I do not know how to get Windows to recognize the USB port as a NIC. Any ideas on how to do that?

Thank you for your support

Comment: What model Pi are you using? Why not connect the PI and PC via Ethernet or WiFi. This would require an WiFI dongle or USB to Ethernet adapter, but should make the rest fairly straightforward.

Comment: Raspberry Pi Model B. Unfortunately, connecting the Pi and PC via Ethernet or WiFi is not an option due to project restrictions.

Comment: This sounds like one of those "I am unable to use any method which may work" requests. Why did you take the job?

Comment: A job's a job. Better question would be why was I assigned such a job, since I can't really grasp its purpose. But anyway, is it possible to set up the linux driver usbnet in order to share the connection over the USB host-to-host cable?

Comment: Check this  question : http://superuser.com/questions/759822/share-windows-computer-internet-connection-with-raspberry-pi. It's reverse of what you're trying to achieve. As per the answer, linux supports ethernet over USB by default so with the help of proper drivers you should be able to do that. You will need to bridge interfaces to make internet available to PC. Good luck. :)

Comment: Just a question of why you are trying to run the pi in between the router and the PC?  Are you trying to monitor network traffic or logs without using the router?

Comment: Yes, the company is making all sorts of experiments with the RPi, even if they are not practically viable. I have just been informed that this Pi will act as network monitor of a specific computer in the company.

Comment: It looks like at this point it's come down to a Windows issue... would the question be better on SuperUser?